# IOS Quartz 2D drawRect and Resizing

Tags: ios, drawrect, cgcontext

I'm using an app called Quarkee to convert a logo from SVG to Quartz 2d code, which works a treat. Only problem is I can't seem to figure out how resize the result. If I set the frame of the UIView, the result from drawRect stays huge in the frame. How do I get it be the size of the frame I'm setting?

An example of the out is below.

Can someone help?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace_1 = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat components_1[] = {0.9961,0.9961,0.9961, 1.0000};
CGColorRef color_1 = CGColorCreate(colorspace_1, components_1);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,color_1);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.4960,0.1090);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,662.9260,0.1090);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,662.9260,227.8780);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,0.4960,227.8780);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,0.4960,0.1090);
CGContextClosePath(context);


CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Comment: Say I call my custom view with it's custom drawRect (as above) UICustomView *myView = [[UICustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 70, 80,30)]; it's frame is correct, but the result drawn in drawRect is too large for the frame. How do I make the drawRect resize the context to the size of the given rect.

Comment: I have tried CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0); for example

Comment: Also to add, the resulting drawRect is HUGE with many many paths, making it infeasible to alter the hard coded coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was to use view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f); to resize the view

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these values:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.4960,0.1090);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,662.9260,0.1090);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,662.9260,227.8780);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,0.4960,227.8780);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,0.4960,0.1090);
```

when the `drawRect` method is called you can use `self.bounds` to take the current rect of your view and adjust those values according to it. You say you have generated this code from a application - those apps usually hardcode the size of the graphics you have drawn, when generate code, so you must see what is the relation between these values with the actual size of the image you have drawn and make them dynamic according to the `self.bounds` size...

Comment: Thanks graver. The drawRect in this situation is drawing a whole logo with hundreds of lines of code into the context and your correct, the points are hard coded, making it infeasible to rewrite them to the bounds of the supplied rect.